# how to reduce the "friction" of the Gallery widget?

Tags: android

I want to make the gallery widget smoother and travel farther down the list of images.

using `android:animationDuration="1000"` certainly makes it smoother

However, I want to reduce the friction as well. How can that be done ?

(Android 2.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set the friction of the Gallery widget.

Comment: weird, that would seem like a pretty big option to leave out. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: What if you extend Gallery, is it possible to make tweaks on the friction on extended Gallery ?

Comment: You would have to copy/paste the source code of Gallery. Just subclassing it won't be enough.

Answer (score 3):

Try to override the onFling method and just multiply the velocity by the factor you want, this will effectively lower the friction.

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {

    velocityX=velocityX*5;

    return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
}
```

Comment: works for me, i wanted to cap the velocity so i just check the magnitude of velocityX and cap it at my max

Answer (score 0):

For the animation, you could try implementing your own interpolator.  That's the only thing I could think of! :)